# Python XML namespaced element text

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces

I want to write a simple SOAP response using Python's ElementTree API (and lxml). Writing the SOAP response involves writing element text (values) with a namespace. [For an example, click here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Ref477795995)

Writing an element with a namespace isn't that big of a problem, but some elements contain text which have a namespace.

I want to create something like:

```
<pleh:a xmlns:pleh="http://pleh">pleh:x</pleh:a>
```

So 'naturally' I do:

```
try:
    from lxml import etree
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

pleh = 'http://pleh'
etree.register_namespace('pleh', pleh)
a = etree.Element('{%s}a' % pleh)
a.text = '{%s}x' % pleh
print(etree.tostring(a))
```

But this prints `<pleh:a xmlns:pleh="http://pleh">{http://pleh}x</pleh:a>`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you find a solution siebz0r?

Comment: @Priyeshj Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "namespaced element text" or "text which have a namespace". Your *element as a whole* is bound to a namespace, that is true. But *element text content* such as `pleh:x` is just a plain string. The `pleh` bit happens to be the (arbitrary) prefix associated with the element's namespace, but it is not significant as far as XML namespaces are concerned.

---

Here you create an XML element, in the `http://pleh` namespace:

```
a = etree.Element('{%s}a' % pleh)
```

The curly braces are interpreted as delimiters of the namespace URI. This is known as ["Clark notation"](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces). The braces do not appear in the serialized XML.

Here you create a string:

```
a.text = '{%s}x' % pleh
```

The text content of the element becomes `{http://pleh}x`. This is not what you expected, but it is perfectly logical (it is not a bug in lxml).

If you need the text content to be `pleh:x`, just use `a.text = 'pleh:x'`

Comment: The string formatting is applied in both cases but the XML module handles them differently. I understand this doesn't 'make sense' in a XML context but this is SOAP. Because of SOAP's static nature it requires some texts to have a namespace. This is demonstrated in the example linked in my question.